# WPF Update List Box From Another View/Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listboxitem

Very new to WPF. I am trying to achieve something relatively simple that is proving to be difficult.

Basically, I want to add an Item to my List Box. The List Box is created in my LiveView xaml/class, but I want to update the contents of the List Box when I push a button in my SettingsView Class.

SettingsView class:

```
public partial class SettingsView : UserControl
   {
       public SettingsView()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }

       private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               var myLiveView = new LiveView();
               myLiveView.updateListBox();
           }
```

}

LiveView class:

```
public partial class LiveView : UserControl
{
    public LiveView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updateListBox()
    {
        CommentListBox.Items.Add("Another item");
    }
}
```

If I do the following, the code works and an item is sucessfully added to my list on startup.

```
public partial class LiveView : UserControl
{
    public LiveView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommentListBox.Items.Add("Another item");
    }
}
```

Why can I only update the UI inside the Liveview class()? What is the right way to go about this? how can I update my ListBox from another class/view? The instance that I'm creating of LiveView doesn't appear to actually do anything. Any help would be much appreiated, thank you.

Comment: you are not using mvvm here. The reason your LiveView usercontrol isn't updating is because you are creating a new one thats not part of the visual tree here:  var myLiveView = new LiveView();  I'd recommend doing this with mvvm (there are lots of basic tutorials for that on youtube or a multitude of tutorial sites) but what you can also do is give your usercontrol a name in the xaml where you declare it with ElementName="YourName" and then use the YourName.updateListBox() method from code behind.

Comment: MVVM seems terribly complicated. Could you provide any useful links? A lot of the tutorials seems to use static data, I need my ListBox to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using MVVM which made this whole process much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance of user control so it is empty now, to handle this please check the delegates and events in both the user controls with respect parent and child navigation.

Comment: could you elaborate? answer wasn't very clear

Comment: Please see how to use delegates and events with exams here with similar requirement.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/341832/wpf-change-the-usercontrol-from-inside-another.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Rajesh, that seems so unnecessarily complicated! all I want to do is add a list box item from a button press within another class. The problem is that I can't access the class properties directly without creating a new instance (which does nothing). I'm struggling to understand how I need 50 lines of code to do this?